# Replace NaN in a dataframe with random values

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame (data_train) with NaN values, A sample is given below:

```
republican                n                          y   
republican                n                          NaN   
democrat                 NaN                         n
democrat                  n                          y
```

I want to replace all the NaN with some random values like .

```
republican                n                           y   
republican                n                          rnd2
democrat                 rnd1                         n
democrat                  n                           y
```

How do I do it.

I tried the following, but had no luck:

```
df_rand = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(data_train.shape[0],data_train.shape[1]))
data_train[pd.isnull(data_train)] = dfrand[pd.isnull(data_train)]
```

when I do the above with a dataframe with random numerical data the above script works fine.

Comment: Your code works for me, you do have a minor typo : `data_train[pd.isnull(data_train)] = df_rand[pd.isnull(data_train)]`

Comment: Hi EdChum, ya I get the typo , It was a copy paste mistake, Anyways the code's still not working for me ..  Does it matter if the column name of the dataframe (data_train) and the dataframe(df_train) are different.

Comment: Ya it worked, It seems the column name for both the dataframes should be same...Thanks

Answer (score 7):

If you want to replace all NaNs from the DF with random values from a list, you can do something like this:

```
import numpy as np

df.applymap(lambda l: l if not np.isnan(l) else np.random.choice([1, 3]))
```

Answer (score 6):

Well, if you use `fillna` to fill the `NaN`, a random generator works only once and will fill all N/As with the same number.

So, make sure that a random number is generated and used each time. 
For a dataframe like this :

```
          Date         A       B
0   2015-01-01       NaN     NaN
1   2015-01-02       NaN     NaN
2   2015-01-03       NaN     NaN
3   2015-01-04       NaN     NaN
4   2015-01-05       NaN     NaN
5   2015-01-06       NaN     NaN
6   2015-01-07       NaN     NaN
7   2015-01-08       NaN     NaN
8   2015-01-09       NaN     NaN
9   2015-01-10       NaN     NaN
10  2015-01-11       NaN     NaN
11  2015-01-12       NaN     NaN
12  2015-01-13       NaN     NaN
13  2015-01-14       NaN     NaN
14  2015-01-15       NaN     NaN
15  2015-01-16       NaN     NaN
```

I used the following code to fill up the `NaNs` in column A:

```
import random
x['A'] = x['A'].apply(lambda v: random.random() * 1000)
```

Which will give us something like:

```
          Date           A       B
0   2015-01-01   96.538211     NaN
1   2015-01-02  404.683392     NaN
2   2015-01-03  849.614253     NaN
3   2015-01-04  590.030660     NaN
4   2015-01-05  203.167519     NaN
5   2015-01-06  980.508258     NaN
6   2015-01-07  221.088002     NaN
7   2015-01-08  285.013762     NaN
```

Comment: The orignal poster wanted to "replace all the NaN with some random values like".
Your solution replaces all NaNs with the random value.

Comment: probably this is not a good solution, what if you want to preserve the original data of column 'A', but this method will change that original data too.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the pandas [update](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.update.html) command, this way:

1) Generate a random DataFrame with the same columns and index as the original one:

```
import numpy as np; import pandas as pd
M = len(df.index)
N = len(df.columns)
ran = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(M,N), columns=df.columns, index=df.index)
```

2) Then use `update`, so that the NaN values in `df` will be replaced by the generated random values

```
df.update(ran)
```

---

In the above example I used values from a standard normal, but you can also use values randomly picked from the original DataFrame:

```
import numpy as np; import pandas as pd

M = len(df.index)
N = len(df.columns)

val = np.ravel(df.values)
val = val[~np.isnan(val)]
val = np.random.choice(val, size=(M,N))
ran = pd.DataFrame(val, columns=df.columns, index=df.index)

df.update(ran)
```

Comment: as far as I understand - your approach replaces all the values to random, not only Nan values

Answer (score 2):

If you want to replace NaN in your column with hot deck technique, I can propose way like this :

```
def hot_deck(dataframe) :
    dataframe = dataframe.fillna(0)
    for col in dataframe.columns :
        assert (dataframe[col].dtype == np.float64) | (dataframe[col].dtype == np.int64)
        liste_sample = dataframe[dataframe[col] != 0][col].unique()
        dataframe[col] = dataframe.apply(lambda row : random.choice(liste_sample) if row[col] == 0 else row[col],axis=1)
    return dataframe
```

After if you prefer just replace NaN with a new random value for each iteration you can do a thing like that. 
You've just to determine the max value of your random choices.

```
def hot_deck(dataframe,max_value) :
    dataframe = dataframe.fillna(0)
    for col in dataframe.columns :
        assert (dataframe[col].dtype == np.float64) | (dataframe[col].dtype == np.int64)
        liste_sample = random.sample(range(max_value),dataframe.isnull().sum())
        dataframe[col] = dataframe.apply(lambda row : random.choice(liste_sample) if row[col] == 0 else row[col],axis=1)
    return dataframe
```

Answer (score 1):

You can randomly fill values by using #tilde operator

```
df['column'].dropna()
df["column"].fillna(np.random.choice(df['column'][~df['column'].isna()]),inplace = True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using fillna() inside loop and setting 'limit' attribute as 1 can help in replacing nan with different random values.

```
import random
while(Series.isnull().sum()!=0):
    Series.fillna(random.uniform(0,100),inplace=True,limit=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try my code. I combined the prior answers to the working example:

```
  M = len(data_train.index)
  N = len(data_train.columns)
  df_rand = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(M,N), columns=data_train.columns, index=data_train.index)
  data_train[pd.isnull(data_train)] = df_rand[pd.isnull(data_train)]
```

It is faster than the use of `apply_map`.

Answer (score 0):

If by random, you actually mean / need unique values, then this fast solution works with all kinds of further, fast modifications possible:

```
mask = df[col].isnull()
df[col][mask] = df[col][mask].index#.astype(str).str.etc...
```

Answer (score 0):

Replacing NaNs according to **discrete column distribution**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def discrete_column_resampling(df, column_names):
        for column in column_names:
            value_counts = df[column].value_counts()
            counts = np.array(value_counts.values.tolist())
            probabilities = counts / np.sum(counts)
            values = value_counts.index.tolist()
            df[column] = df[column].apply(lambda l: l if not pd.isna(l) else \
                np.random.choice(values, p=probabilities))
```

Answer (score -1):

Just  use `fillna` this way

```py
import random
data_train.fillna(random.random())
```

Comment: Hi farhawa, the above piece of code would fill each NaN with the same random number selected, however I need it to be different random number for each NaN.